# If I fail over one database, do the others that share the same mirror endpoint fail over as well?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, failover, mirroring

We have two databases setup for mirroring on a single SQL Server instance: a test database and a production database. Both get mirrored to another server using the exact same endpoints.

If I go into the Database Properties for the test database and click the "Failover" button, will it fail over the production database as well since both databases share a mirror endpoint and their Server Network Addresses properties are the same?

[image]

I am concerned because when I set up mirroring for the 2nd database, I did not have to configure anything new. It just used all the existing information.

If I use the "Failover" button from the Database Properties, will it result in failing over all databases that use that endpoint, or just the specific database that I am viewing the properties for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[@mrdenny's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41856/6173) is accurate that failing over one database will not result in all the other databases failing over as well.

However just to give more overview of what a **database mirroring Endpoint** is:

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179511%28v=sql.100%29.aspx),

Connection management in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and later versions is based on endpoints. An endpoint is a SQL Server object that enables SQL Server to communicate over the network. For database mirroring, a server instance requires its own, dedicated database mirroring endpoint. **All mirroring connections on a server instance use a single database mirroring endpoint.** This endpoint is a special-purpose endpoint used exclusively to receive database mirroring connections from other server instances.

To be more flexible, you can use T-sql for doing manual failover:

**Turn mirroring off** (break mirroring) on the mirror DB.

```
ALTER DATABASE <<DB NAME>> SET PARTNER OFF
```

Set the recover mod the DB to RECOVERY

```
RESTORE DATABASE <<DB NAME>> WITH RECOVERY
```

Fix and orphaned users if you are using SQL authentication

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login ‘Auto_Fix’ , ‘<<username>>’
```

**EDIT:**

Since you are using high safety mode (as per your screenshot), you can use the following from the principal server

```
ALTER DATABASE <<DB NAME>> SET PARTNER FAILOVER
```

Doing so, only the role reversal happens and mirroring direction is reversed - principal becomes mirror and vice-versa. Note that MIRRORING is not BROKEN.

Note that per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179481%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

> Manual failover can be initiated only from the principal server.

If you want to automate the entire failover then refer [Database Mirroring Automation](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/databasemirroringautomation)

Answer (score 8):

No it will not.  The databases are failed over independently from each other.  There's no harm is failing over the test database, the production database will stay where it is.