# What exactly happens during Database Mirroring? What about during a fail over?

Tags: sql-server, replication, mirroring

So I am trying to configure a two server setup, both containing SQL with independent storage. We're using windows server 2012, and I have a question about mirroring. If the server's data bases are in sync then the primary server fails and the mirrored server takes over. How do I re-synchronize the servers after I put the primary(now the one that will act as the mirror) back up? Is that handled automatically?

Edit: I guess I mean after a fail over, how does the old primary get back in sync with the mirror that has been receiving transactions. I think the endpoints are crucial as Kin said.

Comment: Mario, are you using automatic failover?

Comment: @QWE nope, we're using manual failover  (maybe forced manual failover)

Comment: If you run this on your mirror server (which became primary after failover) then your servers will be back to their original roles. 'ALTER DATABASE [yourDatabase] SET PARTNER FAILOVER GO' Please have a look: [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1307815-1549-1.aspx)

Comment: Also this one: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/2009/02/22/Will-the-Mirror-automatically-fail-back-to-the-original-Principal-when-it-comes-back-online/

Answer (score 1):

When you do a failover, a role reversal happens i.e. your primary becomes secondary and your secondary becomes primary.

```
ALTER DATABASE [yourDatabase]
SET PARTNER FAILOVER
GO
```

Doing so, only the role reversal happens (this is what happens when you initiate a failover using above command) and mirroring direction is reversed - principal becomes mirror and vice-versa. Note that MIRRORING is not BROKEN. Refer to my answer : [If I fail over one database, do the others that share the same mirror endpoint fail over as well?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41860/8783) for more details.

You can have your application use `Failover Partner=your_mirror_serve_name`, so that your application is redirected to replica database when a failover happens.

Refer to : [connectionstring in Database Mirror setup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup/)